# Linux tc, u32 filters strange error

Tags: linux

PLease advise me in problem. I'm works on build traffic shaper based on CentOS x86_64 ,Linux version 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64. So, it has about 10 u32 hash-tables, all with 256 divisor. In the default table 800 I hashing 3-rd octet and point packet to the one of this tables, then in hashing 4-th octet and point packet to the class that described bandwidth limitation per user. So, for every IP-address there is a corresponding tc class. We plain to shape around 3000 ip-addresses. And when my script add this IP's into hash tables, I get an error: RTNETLINK answers: File exists. More code here:

```
tc qdisc add dev $inet root handle 2: htb default 8000
tc class add dev $inet parent 2: classid 2:6000 htb rate 100mbit

#this hash-tables are for subnets
for i in {901..912}; do
tc filter add dev $inet parent 2: handle $i: protocol ip u32 divisor 256
done
#adding filters for packet classifying
tc filter add dev $inet protocol ip parent 2: u32 ht 800:: match ip src 172.16.16.0/20 hashkey mask 0x0000ff00 at 12 link 901:
tc filter add dev $inet protocol ip parent 2: u32 ht 901:11: match ip src 172.16.17.0/24 hashkey mask 0x000000ff at 12 link 902:
tc filter add dev $inet protocol ip parent 2: u32 ht 901:12: match ip src 172.16.18.0/24 hashkey mask 0x000000ff at 12 link 903:
#...
#and so on under "link 912:"

#creating classes for every host, place it under root class 2: (100mb for all)
for i in {1..2815}; do tc class add dev $inet parent 2:6000 classid 2:$i htb rate 1mbit ceil 6mbit; done

#place each host in corresponding u32 table
for i in {1..255}; do printf -v hi "%x" "$i";
tc filter add dev $inet protocol ip parent 2: u32 ht 902:$hi: match ip src 172.16.17.$i flowid 2:$i
done
for i in {256..511}; do let j="i-256"; printf -v hi "%x" "$j";
tc filter add dev $inet protocol ip parent 2: u32 ht 903:$hi: match ip src 172.16.18.$j flowid 2:$i
done
#....
#and so on under 2815 hosts
```

And somewhere at the end after command

```
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 2: u32 ht 909:dc: match ip src 172.16.24.220 flowid 2:2012
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
We have an error talking to the kernel
```

I cannot resolve this problem, I thought that there is a filter number limit in the Linux kernel, but some people say me that this is not true, no limit at all. No flowid reused and no hash table handles overlimit occured. What else can caused this error in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated this problem with two other kernels; the modern Ubuntu 12.04 3.5.0-39-generic x86_64 kernel and older Fedora 2.6.33.3-85 i686 kernel. It is present on both of them.

Some u32 filter documentation here: http://ace-host.stuart.id.au/russell/files/tc/doc/cls_u32.txt suggests that the last part of the filter handle, the filter item, should go up to hex 0xFFF, which is 4096 (eg 901:0:0 to 901:0:FFF). This is true when you add filters manually. However, when you add a filter using hashing, you specify the hashtable and bucket, but the filter id is created automatically.

The trouble is that the filter item starts from 800 when created automatically, which means you actually only get 0x800 to 0xFFE filters to use (2048 in total).

You would think that you could switch hashtables for every 2048 filters you add, as you have done in your example, but that's not the case - it will still only allow you to add 2048 filters in total when hashing. I'm not sure if this behaviour is a bug, a limitation, or put there by design.

To get around the issue, you can specify the filter item id manually by placing it before the u32 filter declaration, it must have a zero hashtable and bucket id. That will allow you to add the full 4096 filters, which covers your subnet declaration. It also seems to allow adding 4096 filters per hashtable so you can add even more filters by linking to another hashtable. The last part of your script would need to be like this:

```
#place each host in corresponding u32 table
for i in {1..255}; do
  printf -v hi "%x" "$i";
  tc filter add dev $inet protocol ip parent 2: handle ::$hi u32 ht 902:$hi: match ip src 172.16.17.$i flowid 2:$i
done

for i in {256..511}; do 
  let j="i-256"; 
  printf -v hi "%x" "$i";
  printf -v hj "%x" "$j";
  tc filter add dev $inet protocol ip parent 2: handle ::$hi u32 ht 903:$hj: match ip src 172.16.18.$j flowid 2:$i
done
#....
#and so on under 2815 hosts
```

Here is the code I tested with, it's the same as yours, but I restructured it to use just one hashtable. It should have the same efficiency. It hashes to the required bucket on the last octet only, then matches filters inside the bucket sequentially, rather than sequentially matching and linking to the subnet and then hashing to a bucket.

```
#!/bin/bash

inet='eth0'

# Delete any existing traffic shaping
tc qdisc del dev $inet root
tc qdisc add dev $inet root handle 2: htb default 8000
tc class add dev $inet parent 2: classid 2:6000 htb rate 100mbit

# Create a single hash table (901) with 256 buckets
tc filter add dev $inet parent 2: handle 901: protocol ip u32 divisor 256

# Direct traffic from 172.16.16.0 - 172.16.31.255 to link 901, hash on last octet of src ip 
tc filter add dev $inet protocol ip parent 2: u32 ht 800:: match ip src 172.16.16.0/20 hashkey mask 0x000000ff at 12 link 901:

# Create classes for each host, place it under root class 2: (100mb for all)
for i in {1..2815}; do
    hex_handle=$(echo "obase=16; $i" | bc)
    tc class add dev $inet parent 2:6000 classid 2:$hex_handle htb rate 1mbit ceil 6mbit || exit 1;
done

# Add filters for each possible host
for y in {16..27}; do
    for x in {1..255}; do
        j=$(( (($y - 16) * 255) + $x ));
        hex_bucket=$(echo "obase=16; $x" | bc)
        hex_handle=$(echo "obase=16; $j" | bc)
        tc filter add dev $inet protocol ip parent 2: handle ::$hex_handle u32 ht 901:$hex_bucket match ip src 172.16.$y.$x flowid 2:$hex_handle || exit 1;
    done
done
```